# How does launching `less` differ from launching `cat` in ZSH with regards to the usage of alternate screen and background suspension

Tags: terminal, signals, zsh, terminal-emulator, less-unix

On my OS, by default, ZSH has the `-tostop` (or is the tty?).

This allows backgrounded processes to output to the shell when they have output.

Hence:

```
> stty -tostop
> echo 'random' >/tmp/random
> cat /tmp/random &
[1] 7588
random
[1]  + 7588 done       cat /tmp/random
```

Correspondingly:

```
> stty tostop
> echo 'random' >/tmp/random
> cat /tmp/random &
[1] 3888
[1]  + 3888 suspended (tty output)  cat /tmp/random
```

Reading the documentation and experimenting a bit, I discovered that ZSH has 4 types of suspended processes (you can see this by using `kill -$SIGNAL $PID ; jobs`):

```
job state              - signal that gives you job state
suspended              - SIGTSTP
suspended (signal)     - SIGSTOP
suspended (tty input)  - SIGTTIN
suspended (tty output) - SIGTTOU
```

This would imply that the `3888` process is receiving a SIGTTOU signal.

This all makes sense.

Now my question is that, why is it that `less` doesn't get affected by `stty tostop` or `stty -tostop`?

```
> stty tostop
> less /tmp/random &
[1] 6300
[1]  + 6300 suspended (tty output)  less --LONG-PROMPT --chop-long-lines /tmp/random

> stty -tostop
> less /tmp/random &
[1] 4808
[1]  + 4808 suspended (tty output)  less --LONG-PROMPT --chop-long-lines /tmp/random
```

As you can see in both cases, `less` is always getting suspended in the background.

Now, I know about `less -X`, and I also know about the alternate screen feature that terminal emulators have. **In fact, you can run the above 2 commands with `less -X`, and it results in the same kind of suspension.** Even though `-X` makes it not use alternate screens, less still gets `suspended (tty output)`!

What I want know is the actual mechanics of how `less` is always getting suspended with `suspended (tty output)`, even when `tostop` is getting toggled, and even when `-X` is being toggled too. How can the shell be always sending `SIGTTOU` to `less`, unless there is some other way `less` is getting suspended.

Comment: Alternate screen is unrelated to signal-handling in `less`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(you don't specify your OS, but this answer is based on linux)

Using `strace` you can see `stty` doing an `ioctl` on fd 0 (stdin) toggling one bit in the `c_lflag` value of the termios struct.

`strace` also reveals that `less` will open `/dev/tty` and issue an `ioctl` on it to change the `c_lflag`.

So `less` simply does the same thing as `stty tostop` before outputting anything.

Comment: I see. When you say "fd 0 (stdin)", are you referring to the stdin of the shell itself? Otherwise, which stdin are your referring to? So when less opens a file, it actually opens /dev/tty to send output to there, and you issue ioctl on it aswell. When less opens /dev/tty, is that a connection to the stdin of the shell?

Comment: fd 0 of the shell is the same fd 0 of child processes, unless you redirect its input. `/dev/tty` is the "controlling terminal" of the process so most of the time it's equal to fd 0 of the shell, but if you connect fd 0 to a file (say `less .profile < /dev/null`) you will see that `less` still gets your keyboard input, via `/dev/tty`. However, if you redirect the output of `less` to something not a tty (say `less .profile > /dev/null`) it will notice (using `isatty(1)` which will attempt to `ioctl()` it) and will not open `/dev/tty` and ignore stdin as well. (and behave as `cat`)

Comment: `strace` is your friend (on linux) - it shows all system calls and therefore reveals all actions of the process relating to the "outside world". Simply open a shell to do your `stty` and `less` experiments, and trace that shell from another terminal using `strace -p PID -ff -o filename -s 10240 -v` or similar, which will make a separate output file named `filename.PID` for every child process. To see the inner workings of a process use `ltrace` or a debugger.